# How can I use Gradle to just download JARs?

Tags: gradle, dependency-management

I have a non-standard project layout.

How can I use Gradle to just download a bunch of JAR dependencies into a `lib` directory, under the same directory where `build.gradle` is? For now, I don't need it to do anything else.

Here is what I have so far:

```
apply plugin: "java"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

buildDir = "."
libsDirName = "lib"

dependencies {
    runtime group: "...", name: "...", version: "..."
}
```

If I run `gradle build`, it builds an empty JAR file in the `lib` directory, instead of downloading my dependencies there.

Switching "lib" with "." in the properties does not work either.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Something like the following should work:

```
apply plugin: 'base'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

configurations {
    toCopy
}

dependencies {
    toCopy 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0'
    toCopy 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.4.3'
}

task download(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.toCopy 
    into 'lib'
}
```

Comment: Type the command `gradle download` to execute the created task

Comment: Note that this also downloads transitive dependencies which may, or may not, be a redundant overhead.

Comment: @Alex if you want to avoid transitive dependencies, this can easily be handled by setting `{ transitive = false }` in the dependency configuration. Such as shown [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/resolution_rules.html#sec:disabling_resolution_transitive_dependencies)

Answer (score 0):

for downloading `implementation`, `runtimeOnly` dependencies, could use [`configurations.runtimeClasspath`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html#sec:java_library_configurations_graph):

```
apply plugin: 'base'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0'
    runtimeOnly 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.4.3'
}

task copyDependencies(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.runtimeClasspath
    into 'lib'
}
```

then execute `gradle copyDependencies`