# Getting all files of an artifact from maven repository

Tags: maven, gradle, download, dependencies, maven-central

Our organization works in an isolated network so when we want to use libraries we need to retrieve them from maven-central and upload then to our own maven repository.

I am searching for way do download all the files of my required dependencies,
I have used gradle `gradle eclipseClasspath` to do this but it is not downloading all the files. for example `org.jacoco:jacoco:0.7.8` contains a zip file and when I look in the `GRADLE_USER_HOME` I can not find the zip.

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    compile 'org.jacoco:jacoco:0.7.8'
}
```

What should I do?

Comment: Simply use a repository manager and let a build run and all of your needed artifacts have been downloaded into your repository manager. That's it?

Comment: @khmarbaise what is this repository manager, can you give me an example?

Comment: Take a look here: https://maven.apache.org/repository-management.html

Comment: I don't understand, we need to download the artifacts so we could upload them to out isolated repository manager(nexus), Do you suggest I use a repository manager to download the artifacts or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted a simple solution, for now I have made this ugly one https://github.com/idosu/scripts/blob/master/gradle/full-download-from-central.gradle

usage:

```
apply from: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/idosu/scripts/master/gradle/full-download-from-central.gradle'
dependencies {
    compile 'org.jacoco:jacoco:0.7.8'
}
```

windows: `set GRADLE_USER_HOME=deps & gradle --no-daemon -b eclipseClasspath createRepo`

shell: `export GRADLE_USER_HOME=deps; gradle --no-daemon -b eclipseClasspath createRepo`

The result will be in `build/repo`

---

A better way to do this is figuring out how `eclipseClasspath` resolves all the dependencies with all the parent poms. because using `project.configurations.compile.resolvedConfiguration.lenientConfiguration.allModuleDependencies` does not do the trick

Answer (score 2):

You could use [this gradle task](https://gist.github.com/bmuschko/e4e04abca105c397145e) to download the dependencies to a local directory.

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39981143/1089967) for downloading sources and javadocs (if available) for dependencies

Comment: For my understanding `withArtifacts(JvmLibrary, SourcesArtifact)` is the way to download the sources, but how do I manage to download the zip which is not source nor javadoc, I have tried to use `withArtifacts(Component, Artifact)` but it does not seems to work