# Gradle: How do I copy POM files to WAR?

Tags: gradle, jar, war, pom.xml

The WEB-INF\lib folder in our WAR file should serve as a flatDir repository for our users. I presume I need to supply a POM file for each JAR, so that transitive dependencies would be resolved.

How do I copy POM files for each JAR to WEB-INF\lib folder in my WAR file?

My root project script:

```
apply plugin: 'war'

jar.enabled = false
war {
    dependencies {
        subprojects.each { runtime it }

        providedCompile servlet
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the [flatDir documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sec:flat_dir_resolver) which states

```
Note that this type of repository does not support any meta-data formats like Ivy XML or Maven POM files.
```

If you want to download all dependencies (and pom files) to a maven directory structure you can use [this gist](https://gist.github.com/bmuschko/e4e04abca105c397145e). To download javadocs and sources too see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39975780/how-can-i-use-gradle-to-download-dependencies-and-their-source-files-and-place-t/39981143#39981143)