# Using command line to tell gradle to download all the source jars

Tags: gradle, command-line, dependencies

Looking at [how to tell gradle to download all the source jars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10156847/how-to-tell-gradle-to-download-all-the-source-jars) and [How can I force gradle to redownload dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13565082/how-can-i-force-gradle-to-redownload-dependencies), I wonder is there a way to  tell gradle to download all the source jars from command line (without touching `.gradle` files)

Answer (score 1):

To download/copy jars and pom files to a folder see [this gist](https://gist.github.com/bmuschko/e4e04abca105c397145e)

To download/copy sources too see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39975780/how-can-i-use-gradle-to-download-dependencies-and-their-source-files-and-place-t/39981143#39981143) (this could be adapted to include javadocs too)

If you don't want to edit the `build.gradle` you can use an [init-script](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/init_scripts.html) to add a task to each project.

Eg dependency-download.gradle

```
allprojects { Project p ->
    p.tasks.add('downloadDependencies', DownloadDependenciesTask)
} as Action<Project>

class DownloadDependenciesTask extends DefaultTask
    // TODO implement
}
```

Then from command line

```
gradle --init-script dependency-download.gradle downloadDependencies
```