# Gradle: How to debug a source code of a dependency

Tags: java, gradle, dependency-management, jdb

I'm using `jdb` debugger and I'd like to step into the dependency code. I'm using `gradle` as well.
Here is my `build.gradle`

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id "io.spring.dependency-management" version "1.1.0"
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.0'
}

task runApp(type: JavaExec) {
    main = 'App'
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
}
```

I'm using a plugin, that should automatically download and manage the source code for my dependencies (`io.spring.dependency-management`). I'm not sure, if this is the right plugin.

But when I run

```
$ gradle clean
$ gradle build
```

and then I run `jdb` I can view my source code file but I can't view (list) the source code of a dependency.

What I'd like to achieve?

1. step into the code of a dependency
2. list the source code with the `list` command

How can I do it?

Comment: The Spring dependency management plugin has nothing to do with source code. It only allows to control dependency versions coming from BOMs. Actually, it is a relict from times when Gradle had no built-in BOM support. Even the maintainer of that plugin recommends to not use it anymore, but instead use the built-in BOM support. But anyway this has nothing to do with your actual question either way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this answer to download the sources of your dependencies : [How can I use Gradle to download dependencies and their source files and place them all in one directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39975780/how-can-i-use-gradle-to-download-dependencies-and-their-source-files-and-place-t/39981143#39981143)

Then, use the sourcepath jdb option to let him know where the sources are:
`jdb -sourcepath ".:/path/to/download"`.

Comment: Be very careful when doing this. Artifact resolution queries for example are not variant / attribute aware. There is unfortunately not yet a proper replacement that is which is the main reason it is still in there and not deprecated, but it should be used with caution.